# How do I "assign" a part of a disk to a folder?

Tags: drivers, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Sorry for my ignorance when it comes to terminology, i'm not a server ops guy.

I have a 600GB disk which 164GB is only used.

lsblk gives:

```
sdb      8:16   0   600G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   0   164G  0 part /var/lib/solr4
```

I'd like to "assign" (for lack of better words) 250GB to folder `/var/lib/solr6` and 150GB to folder `/tmp/`

What do I do to achieve this?

Comment: I just searched for it and found these links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148715/how-to-set-limit-on-directory-size-in-linux

https://github.com/floriandejonckheere/fusequota

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create desired partitions in sizes you want

   On your physical disk, create extra partitions.  You can use a tool like `parted`, `gparted` (or a number of other tools).   `parted` isn't a layman level tool, instead use `gparted` (or `kde partition manager` if using KDE etc) to create partitions using empty space.
2. Get the UUID's for create partitions using `blkid`  (*UUID is a unique identifier and better than /dev/sdxy labels*)

> ```
> guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   blkid
>
> /dev/sda1: UUID="afa7971f-3dd5-4b30-9c98-0af3e56a6f2b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6c8394c6-01"
> ```

3. Add  those partitions to your file system table (`/etc/fstab`).  You can use existing partitions as example, but `man` pages (reference manual pages) are helpful too  (*using UUIDs from prior step*).

> ```
> UUID=afa7971f-3dd5-4b30-9c98-0af3e56a6f2b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
> ```

*Steps 2 & 3 contain examples from my running system showing how the UUID of my / partition appears in my `/etc/fstab`.  The / is where it's mounted, ext4 is the file-system type, the errors=remount-ro is an option (you'll likely just use defaults), and '0 1' are the fs_freq & fs_passno entries, you'll use "0 0" most likely adjusting for your needs.  Use `man fstab` for more exacting detail*

Comment: Thanks for telling what I need to do, could you advice me in how to do in in layman terms? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you will need to partition the disk (using Gpart for example) and then mount the partitions to your desired locations.